# Schedule Primefaces looks bad

Tags: primefaces, schedule

I'm using a template with three sections, top, left (sliding menu) and content. In all my pages this works fine because the content looks right beside the left section. But with the schedule just the header is in the right section or displays fine but the body's schedule is way down, after the section of the left.

[image: this is how it looks!]

thanks for the help.

Comment: You could check in Firebug or some other browser's dev tools if this is a css issue. Apparently the schedule's body starts right below the left menu section.

Comment: I have this same issue. what was the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I've found it. You need to add position: relative; top: -220px; to the Css of the calendar rendering in my calendar.css  Hope this helped!

Comment: I put -220, but you need to put whatever space you want ti to move up